# JMeter: Can each User in Thread Group run multiple HTTP Sampler?

Tags: jmeter

I need to send 40K HTTP requests to the server at the same time. Then repeat this scenario every 15mins.

Now, in JMeter I cannot spawn 40K users. Right now, I am successfully able to spawn 500 users in a Thread Group. So I was thinking if I can keep user count as 500 and make each user execute 80 HTTP Samplers, then my job will be done!

But I don't know how to achieve this. Can you please guide me here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Request is being executed by thread. If you are able to get only 500 threads at a time your load will be limited to these 500 concurrent threads. There are following options available:

1. Switch to i.e. [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) tool which is more optimized for multi-threading and less memory-consuming than JMeter.
2. Consider [JMeter Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html) when on JMeter master engine orchestrates multiple slaves to produce combined load
3. Take a look into [JMeter Load Testing Cloud](http://blazemeter.com/) offerings